# Exceeded rate limits for bigquery insertAll method

Tags: python-3.x, google-bigquery

I deployed a flask endpoint to the Google AppEngine. It receives a payload, parses it, and sends the data to two different bigquery tables.

My setup:
I'm using `python 3.7`, `flask`, the `google AppEngine`, and the `google.cloud.bigquery Client()` class.

In a nutshell, this is what happens:

```
- endpoint is called
- endpoint gets payload and parses it
- sends data (1 row) to first bigquery table using client.insert_rows_json(table, [data])
- sends data (1 row) to second bigquery table using client.insert_rows(table, [data])
```

The error(s):

Reading the appengine log of my service I found this error:

```
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tabledata/insertAll
Traceback (most recent call last): File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py", line 184, in retry_target return target() File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/_http.py", line 423, in api_request raise exceptions.from_http_response(response) google.api_core.exceptions.Forbidden: 403 GET https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/PROJECT_NAME/datasets/DATASET_NAME/tables/TABLE_NAME: Exceeded rate limits: too many api requests per user per method for this user_method. For more information, see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/troubleshooting-errors
```

My hypothesis is that two calls to the BQ API exceed the user-method limit, is it plausible?
Since both Client() methods use the same API method, insertAll, which is a `streaming method`, I doubt it's a matter of quotas.

Another issue I found, is that the table filled by the first call gets ~2% fewer entries than the table filled by the second call (which is the one for which I noticed the error). What could be the reason?

I already checked some payloads not present in the first table and they are legit so I don't think it's a matter of their format not matching the table schema.

## EDIT: solved

I ended up following shollyman's advice to drop get_table and instead pass to insert_rows() or insert_rows_json() a [Table](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.table.Table.html) object initialized with a [TableReference](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.table.TableReference.html#google.cloud.bigquery.table.TableReference) and a schema as a list of [SchemaField](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.schema.SchemaField.html) instances.

#### Code:

```py
from google.cloud import bigquery
client = bigquery.Client()
```

**old**

```py
# get table info -- API call
table_id = '{}.{}.{}'.format(PROJECT_ID, DATASET_ID, TABLE_ID)
table = client.get_table(table_id)
# insert row -- API call
client.insert_rows(table, [data])
```

**new**

```py
# create table ref
dataset_ref = bigquery.dataset.DatasetReference(project=PROJECT_ID, dataset_id=DATASET_ID)
table_ref = bigquery.table.TableReference(dataset_ref=dataset_ref, table_id=TABLE_ID)
# specify table schema
schema = [
        bigquery.schema.SchemaField(name='field1', field_type='TIMESTAMP', mode='NULLABLE'),
        bigquery.schema.SchemaField(name='field2', field_type='STRING', mode='NULLABLE')
              ]
# create table instance 
table = bigquery.table.Table(table_ref=table_ref, schema=schema)
# insert row -- API call
client.insert_rows(table, [data])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indicating that your code is getting table metadata too aggressively via the [tables.get API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables/get).  Do you do something like reload the table stats on every insert, or fetch schema, etc?  Streaming inserts allows many orders of magnitude more QPS than retrieving table metadata.

Comment: Thanks for the response!
I do indeed invoke `get_table()` twice in the script (once for each insertion). Do you think this could be the issue? The problem is that I want to write to two different tables and I'm not aware of a way to avoid calling `get_table()` twice. Any ideas?

Comment: Coupling high and low QPS methods together is going to be problematic as you've seen.  Without knowing why you're doing it I can't provide much guidance, but you shouldn't need it at all for inserting data.  You can pass both methods a [TableReference](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.table.TableReference.html#google.cloud.bigquery.table.TableReference) rather than a full metadata representation.

Comment: Thanks for your pointers. I ended up passing to the insert methods a Table instance with a TableReference and a schema as a list of SchemaField objects. It was a bit confusing because get_table()  is used in the [official python example](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery#bigquery_table_insert_rows-python) for streaming inserts and I found the documentation for insert_rows and insert_rows_json a bit lacking.